# Testing D3 Applications with click and drag events

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, svg, d3.js

I'm creating an application based loosely on this example:
http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how to write tests for it.
Screenshot diff tools aren't the way to go as I don't want to test how the visualisation looks, but how it behaves.

Ideally what I would like to do is be able to check events.

For example, click the middle of the svg and check if a node has been created. Get the locations of two nodes, drag from one to the other and check if a link has been created.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: You could do this with [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is end-to-end testing tools. For Angular apps, [Protractor](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/) is nice.

However, be careful, the native HTML5 drag-n-drop events are not well supported on Chrome, as described here: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3604

Comment: Looking for solution on to do the same testing in Ember.

Comment: Protractor is for Angular but it's based on Selenium, a generic E2E testing framework. I'm sure you can use it for testing Ember apps.